# During the time of the German Empire, were Polish or Jewish people permitted to join the Social Democratic Party?

Tags: jews, poland, imperial-germany, demography, socialism

According to Wikipedia, the Social Democratic Party (SPD) of Germany was founded in 1890. The German empire was founded in 1871:

[image: {German empire shown in green on a map of Europe}]

Inside of this territory, there were many people who were ethnically non-German, for example, (ethnically) Jewish, Polish, Latvian, Lithuanian, etc. Were they allowed to join the SPD?

**What proportion of the SPD was composed of these, and other, ethnicities?**
It would be great to have a comprehensive look at the demographics. However, the time period I am interested in is about 1900 - 1914; also curious during 1914-1918.

I have already read the wikipedia page about the [history of the SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany#German_Revolution_(1918%E2%80%931919)) but it has no information about demographics. And a google search about this seems to focus on the keywords "Polish" "SPD" and ignores the "before 1918" keywords. I've tried a bunch.

Edit: To clarify what I'm looking for, I imagine a circular pie chart, with some % German, some % Polish, % Jewish, % Latvian, etc.

Comment: It is worth noting that there was a *Polnische Liste* representing ethnic Poles in the Reichstag. So even though Poles were not excluded from other parties, they were not represented by them.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany), the General German Workers' Association was founded in 1863 and it merged with the Social Democratic Workers' Party to form the Socialist Workers' Party of Germany in 1875, and that in turn changed its name to the SPD in 1890. Hmm.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks! Updated.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by Jewish and Polish in this question. For  instance, Jewish might mean ethnicity or religion.

Comment: Why do you think that SPD limited the nationality of their members? Don't forget, that till WWI it was a pure Marxist party, and Marxism disallows nationalism. And Marx himself was a Jew. If they only tried something of that kind, they would immediately get very bad press from Engels or Marx themselves.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I imagine a circular pie chart, with some % German, some % Polish,  % Latvian, etc. I think it would be fine to have Jewish as an ethnicity or as a religion in the scope of this question.

Comment: You should clarify in the question itself. If you look at the comments in one of the answers, it is an issue (who is Polish). BTW, given Marxist character of the SDP, I would be asti6nded to find any non-atheists there.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 16):

[Rosa Luxemburg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Luxemburg) was a fairly prominent SPD member before WWI. She was from a Jewish family in Poland.

[This SPD-affiliated page](https://www.fes.de/feshistory/juedische-mdr-und-spaltung-der-sozialdemokratie) says that in 1914, the SPD had 12 Jewish Reichstag members (out of a total of [110 SPD seats](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1912_German_federal_election))

Comment: Nitpick, I would call the FES "affilated" rather than "semi-official." Both sides acknowledge that they are legally different entities, but both the relation is close.

Comment: Rosa could not vote nor being voted. A sad membership.

Comment: @Grim Only since 1908 were women allowed to join (any) party and since 1918 allowed to vote.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Rosa joined 1898 the SPD, SPD was a political party. But yes, very sad.

Answer (score 4):

SPD emerged from the merger of the Lassalle's [General German Workers Association (ADAV)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_German_Workers%27_Association) and Marxist [Social Democratic Workers party](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Workers%27_Party_of_Germany). Both Lassalle and Marx (as well as many of their followers) were of Jewish origin, although estranged from Judaism and Jewish traditional life. So it is fair to say that Jewishness have never been a problem in the SPD.

It is also worth mentioning that Lassalle was from Breslau, so he could be also viewed as a Polish Jew.

**Remark**
Technically, Marx father converted to Christianity, and Marx' upbringing was formally Christian. Lassalle was raised in a traditional Jewish family, although he had been long dead by the time of the merger.

Comment: Considering a person from Breslau at that time to be "Polish" is quite a stretch and not supported by the demographics of that city. It was a overwhelmingly German city back than. It is Polish now because of the ethnic cleansing of Silesia from 1945 on.

Comment: @SirCornflakes my understanding is that the family changed their original name to Polish-sounding "Lasel" after moving to Breslau, and that they spoke fluent Polish.

Comment: Ferdinand Lasalle himself published in German and was member of a German *Burschenschaft*, so there is no reason to think that he identified himself as a Pole. His family came to Breslau from a part of Upper Silesia (Loslau, today Wodzisław Śląski) that was handed over to Poland in 1921 after a plebiscite.

Comment: @SirCornflakes The question is not about how he identified himself, but about whether somebody's Polish and Jewish background could pose a problem to SPD. The rest is not relevant to the Q.

Comment: @SirCornflakes what about "Loslau" - is that Polish enough? (see here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/23506487) If you want to collaborate on improving this answer, I am open to suggestions... even though I consider your confrontational attitude as unfriendly, and contrary to the SE rules.

Comment: I don't think that Lasalle can be construed as an example of a Polish member of SPD. There should be more clear-cut examples of that. What Leslau is concerned: Only his father's family is from there, Lasalle also had a mother.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Lassalle was not a member of SDP - he was the founder of ADAV, which would later merge with SDAP to form SPD. The conjecture here is that, given their antecedents, SPD was unlikely to discriminate against Jews.

Comment: [Ferdinand Johann Gottlieb Lassalle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Lassalle) is not a very polish sounding name. Population of Breslau 1900: 422709 ; of that 19743 were Jews and between 8000 and 20000 Polish (depending on the source), which would be for each group less than 5%.

Comment: @MarkJohnson if you followed the discussion above - the last name was derived from "Loslau", and later francized during Lassalle's life in Paris. It is also not uncommon for Jews to gave official name and internal name, used in the family or synagogue - Ferdinand could have been Jacob or Yehuda or something like that for his relatives.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers so far have given clear indication of Jews being admitted to the SPD and its parent organisations.

Here's a clearly Polish member of the party [Julian Marchlewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Marchlewski)

P.S. I tried Large Language Models on this question, and they don't give much useful information. The consistently drop the names of Rosa Luxemburg and Adolf Warski, but one of them claims not to have enough information (bard-jan-24-gemini-pro) and the other (llama-2-7b-chat) went on to invent some Polish social democrats, or to assign some existing persons to the SPD without verifiable source (their Wikipedia entry does not mention any political affiliation)